# User logout warning and auto timeout

Tags: javascript

I have a page that alerts user every 10 seconds whether he wants to stay logged in or not. If he chooses yes, he will stay logged in and the timer runs again and he is alerted after another 10 seconds. If no, he is logged out immediately.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeshwanthvshenoy/zu97asxs/) of the below code.

```
<script>
(function dimer()
{
setTimeout(function()
{
var x=window.confirm("Session is about to time-out !!! Press OK to Continue - CANCEL to logout !!!")
if (x){
dimer();
auto();
}
else
{
window.location.href = '../logoff.php';
}
},10000);
})()
</script>
<script>
function auto()
{
setTimeout(function()
{
alert("You have been logged out.");
window.location.href = '../logoff.php';
},20000);
}
</script>
```

What happens is when i click yes, the dimer and auto functions run and again after 10 secs i get prompt. If i again click yes, and after 10 secs i should again get the prompt but whereas i get the expired warning.

Comment: what do you mean by "*auto timeout doesnt seem to run*"? would the `log out` will alert if the user choose cancel?

Comment: i have updated question in detail try the fiddle and you will know. Try clicking yes 3 times in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are trying to alert it every 10 sec.
Use

> setInterval(functionName,interval);

instead of `setTimeout()`

Hope this help you.

Comment: not only alert i am doing a part of the functionality using this. What happens is when i click yes, the dimer and auto functions run and again after 10 secs i get prompt. If i again click yes, and after 10 secs i should again get the prompt but whereas i get the expired warning.

Comment: Try the fiddle and you will know what i mean. Try clicking yes 3 times in the fiddle.

Comment: That's because you are calling function auto() at wrong place. You should place it in else case, because if you click OK in a confirm box, it will return true. So it will enter into the if case and auto() will be called.

Comment: if the prompt comes up and user doesn't respond for 10 secs even after pop-up comes, then at 20th sec, he will automatically be logged out. This is what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: You need to setInterval inside dimer() and put setTimeout for auto(). Also, put call to auto() in the else case.